# How to find laplace transform of $y(t)$ for a third order differential equation?

Tags: laplace-transform

[Laplace Transform Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1beX.jpg)

I am working on a problem that needs me to solve the Laplace transform on the equation,
$$y'''+ 4y''-2y'+y=e^t \hspace{5mm} y(0) = 1, y'(0) = -1, y''(0) = 3.$$

I've gotten it down to the $Y(s)$ Laplace form, however, I am unsure on how to get the $y(t)$ function by using the inverse Laplace method.

Comment: Hello! May you please edit your question with MathJax and provide the steps and fully transcribe that image? A guide to MathJax can be found here:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/1098096

Comment: If the "2" was replaced by "4" then the equation allows for a nice solution by Laplace transform use. Otherwise it seems that a cubic equation needs to be solved and then roots are used in the exponentials for the inverse solution.